# Visual Studio 2017, change to data model changes all line endings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

Two of us are working on the same project. If either of us makes a small change to entity framework (edmx) it seems that all *.cs files in the project are altered and in my case extra line endings are added (i.e. like double line spacing). So if I make a data model change I have changes made to all *.cs files which then get pushed to GIT, and if he then makes a change the same thing happens.
Is it possible to stop VS making changes to all *.cs files?
If not, is there a setting to tell it what sort of line spacing (ending) I want?
Note that the problem doesn't occur when opening the project (i.e. the option to not check line endings) - it only happens when a change is made to entity framework.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitattributes` file?

Comment: Nope. Only a .gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach could be not add a `.gitattributes` (beside `.gitignore`) file, if you actually haven't one.
If you modify the `*.edmx` file the changes will be done on model classes too. Therefore there should be modifications.

The `.gitattributes` could contain:

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto

# Custom for Visual Studio
*.sln text eol=crlf
*.csproj text eol=crlf
*.vbproj text eol=crlf
*.fsproj text eol=crlf
*.dbproj text eol=crlf

*.vcxproj text eol=crlf
*.vcxitems text eol=crlf
*.props text eol=crlf
*.filters text eol=crlf

*.cs     diff=csharp

# Standard to msysgit
*.doc    diff=astextplain
*.DOC    diff=astextplain
*.docx diff=astextplain
*.DOCX diff=astextplain
*.dot  diff=astextplain
*.DOT  diff=astextplain
*.pdf  diff=astextplain
*.PDF    diff=astextplain
*.rtf    diff=astextplain
*.RTF    diff=astextplain
```